# Angular 5 won't deploy to Azure App Services

Tags: node.js, angular, azure

We are attempting to deploy an Angular 5.1.3 App to an Azure App Service. The deployments are triggered by commits to a GitHub repo. Each time we deploy the deployment takes several minutes and then results in the below message

Can anyone help identify the root issue?

```
ERROR in ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
    Module not found : error : Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.browser.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\home\site\repository\Operations\ClientApp' [D:\home\site\repository\Operations\STB_Operations.csproj]
           @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts 6:0-95

    EXEC : ERROR in error : Please update @angular/cli. Angular 5+ requires at least Angular CLI 1.5+ [D:\home\site\repository\Operations\STB_Operations.csproj]
              at throwNotSupportedError (D:\home\site\repository\Operations\packages\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.ts:132:9)
              at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (D:\home\site\repository\Operations\packages\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.ts:80:11)
              at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then (D:\home\site\repository\Operations\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:430:58)
              at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
              at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
              at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
              at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
              at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
      Child
          Hash: 04a987447071d4f6074c
          Time: 23130ms
                   Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
          main-server.js  3.29 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main-server

          ERROR in ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts
    Module not found : error : Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.server.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\home\site\repository\Operations\ClientApp' [D:\home\site\repository\Operations\STB_Operations.csproj]
           @ ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts 8:0-94

    EXEC : ERROR in error : Please update @angular/cli. Angular 5+ requires at least Angular CLI 1.5+ [D:\home\site\repository\Operations\STB_Operations.csproj]
              at throwNotSupportedError (D:\home\site\repository\Operations\packages\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.ts:132:9)
              at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (D:\home\site\repository\Operations\packages\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.ts:80:11)
              at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then (D:\home\site\repository\Operations\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:430:58)
              at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
              at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
              at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
              at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
              at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
    D:\home\site\repository\Operations\STB_Operations.csproj(117,5): error MSB3073: The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" exited with code 2.
    Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish "D:\home\site\repository\Operations\STB_Operations.csproj" --output "D:\local\Temp\8d555638ef9d872" --configuration Release
    An error has occurred during web site deployment.
    \r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\70.10102.3204\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

For context, here is our **package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "STB_Operations",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.3",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "karma": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "^4.4.6",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.3",
    "ajv": "^5.5.2",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.8",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "less": "^2.7.3",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "log4js": "^2.4.1",
    "preboot": "^5.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "tslib": "^1.8.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  }
}
```

Here is the deployment script if it's part of the issue

```
#!/bin/bash

# ----------------------
# KUDU Deployment Script
# Version: 0.2.2
# ----------------------

# Helpers
# -------

exitWithMessageOnError () {
  if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "An error has occurred during web site deployment."
    echo $1
    exit 1
  fi
}

# Prerequisites
# -------------

# Verify node.js installed
hash node 2>/dev/null
exitWithMessageOnError "Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment."

# Setup
# -----

SCRIPT_DIR="${BASH_SOURCE[0]%\\*}"
SCRIPT_DIR="${SCRIPT_DIR%/*}"
ARTIFACTS=$SCRIPT_DIR/../artifacts
KUDU_SYNC_CMD=${KUDU_SYNC_CMD//\"}

if [[ ! -n "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE" ]]; then
  DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=$SCRIPT_DIR
fi

if [[ ! -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" ]]; then
  NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=$ARTIFACTS/manifest

  if [[ ! -n "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" ]]; then
    PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH
  fi
fi

if [[ ! -n "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" ]]; then
  DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=$ARTIFACTS/wwwroot
else
  KUDU_SERVICE=true
fi

if [[ ! -n "$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" ]]; then
  # Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  npm install kudusync -g --silent
  exitWithMessageOnError "npm failed"

  if [[ ! -n "$KUDU_SERVICE" ]]; then
    # In case we are running locally this is the correct location of kuduSync
    KUDU_SYNC_CMD=kuduSync
  else
    # In case we are running on kudu service this is the correct location of kuduSync
    KUDU_SYNC_CMD=$APPDATA/npm/node_modules/kuduSync/bin/kuduSync
  fi
fi

# Node Helpers
# ------------

selectNodeVersion () {
  if [[ -n "$KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD" ]]; then
    SELECT_NODE_VERSION="$KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD \"$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE\" \"$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET\" \"$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP\""
    eval $SELECT_NODE_VERSION
    exitWithMessageOnError "select node version failed"

    if [[ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/__nodeVersion.tmp" ]]; then
      NODE_EXE=`cat "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/__nodeVersion.tmp"`
      exitWithMessageOnError "getting node version failed"
    fi

    if [[ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/.tmp" ]]; then
      NPM_JS_PATH=`cat "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/__npmVersion.tmp"`
      exitWithMessageOnError "getting npm version failed"
    fi

    if [[ ! -n "$NODE_EXE" ]]; then
      NODE_EXE=node
    fi

    NPM_CMD="\"$NODE_EXE\" \"$NPM_JS_PATH\""
  else
    NPM_CMD=npm
    NODE_EXE=node
  fi
}

##################################################################################################################################
# Deployment
# ----------

echo Handling node.js deployment.

# 1. KuduSync
if [[ "$IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT" -ne "1" ]]; then
  "$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" -v 50 -f "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE" -t "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" -p "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.sh"
  exitWithMessageOnError "Kudu Sync failed"
fi

# 2. Select node version
selectNodeVersion

# 3. Install NPM packages
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET/package.json" ]; then
  cd "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
  eval $NPM_CMD install --production
  eval $NPM_CMD install --only=dev
  exitWithMessageOnError "npm failed"
  cd - > /dev/null
fi

# 4. Angular Prod Build
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET/.angular-cli.json" ]; then
  cd "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
  eval ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod
  exitWithMessageOnError "Angular build failed"
  cd - > /dev/null
fi

##################################################################################################################################

# Post deployment stub
if [[ -n "$POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION" ]]; then
  POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION=${POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION//\"}
  cd "${POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION_DIR%\\*}"
  "$POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION"
  exitWithMessageOnError "post deployment action failed"
fi

echo "Finished successfully."
```

Comment: I'm getting something like this as well.  If I figure it out before you, I'll let you know.  Can you do the same?  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message:

> ERROR in error : Please update @angular/cli. Angular 5+ requires at least Angular CLI 1.5+

You may need to add `@angular/cli` reference to dev dependencies:

```
"@angular/cli": "1.6.3"
```

and install it globally:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: I have no access to the underlying machine with App Services hosting in Azure. But when we add the cli package it just produces a new error `EXEC : npm ERR! error : EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'D:\home\site\repository\Operations\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\dashdash\node_modules'`

Comment: How about using Kudu console (`https://<yourappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`) to run the command `npm install -g @angular/cli`?

Comment: Just tried and then ran `npm -v` to verify. In the end, the deployment still results in the EPERM error.